# Scurry, scamping(?)

Tags: vocabulary

When a little boy is tapping lightly in front of a washroom because he wants to pee but couldn't get in as it is occupied already. 
What words are used to express the image of the feet tapping: he is **scamping** or **scurring**?

Comment: Neither ***scamping*** nor ***scurring*** are valid English words. You need ***scampering*** or ***scurrying***. In many contexts they mean the same, but sometimes ***to scurry*** carries stronger connotations of moving quickly *with a purpose*, whereas ***to scamper*** (often followed by ***about***) is more likely to be used in the context of "gamboling, prancing, cavorting" (in "undirected" playful mode, as of children). Your little boy desperate to pee might be said to be ***jiggling*** his feet, but he probably wouldn't scamper or scurry, *because he's not going anywhere*.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives for

> tapping

might be

> stamping
>   stomping
>   beating
>   pounding

but usually a child might be

> hopping

while waiting to get to the toilet, anything to distract themself.